# Effective Manager drills

Tags: project-management-style

I am a tech lead, who had recently transitioned to becoming a people manager. It was something I wanted to try out, though I wasnt quite sure what it meant.

After 6 months at it, I am still not quite sure what it means. Oddly enough, despite the efforts from my bosses are having a hard time precisely quantifying what this job entails. I had two questions:

1) Can you suggest a good book for a novice like me to read and learn from?

2) When I think of a skill (my background is in mathematics), I think of  mastering the minutia of it through "drills" (exercises/assignments/what not) in an offline setting before getting to the real online task (solving some real world problem). Simply put, my view is that the better I am at the drills, the better I get at real world problems. What are the equivalent offline "drills" in management, and could you suggest where/how I could practice it in an offline setting? Textbooks/best practices/ anything would help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be list-generating.

Comment: My apologies if this appears to not be pertinent to this forum. Could you please suggest a better place to post this question/seek advice on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the forum. I think that the actual answer would depend a lot on your values, type of management you do, etc. *From my perspective*, these are my favorite 5 at the moment:

1. [The Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html)
2. [Thanks for the Feedback](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Thanks-Feedback-Science-Receiving-Well/dp/0670922633/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1547225310&sr=8-1&keywords=thanks%20for%20the%20feedback)
3. [Leading with Dignity](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Leading-Dignity-Create-Culture-Brings/dp/0300229631/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1547225343&sr=1-1&keywords=leading%20with%20dignity)
4. [The Charisma Myth](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Charisma-Myth-Science-Personal-Magnetism/dp/B01153ITZ8/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1547225381&sr=8-2&keywords=the%20charisma%20myth)
5. [How Google Works](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Google-Works-Eric-Schmidt/dp/1444792490/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1547225421&sr=8-1&keywords=how%20google%20works)

There are many equivalents to "drills" in these books, you can practice some exercises offline before trailing them with your team, but to be honest, in my experience, it is a "trial and error" process that needs to be in constant adaptation.